# Why does this regex pattern fail to match the string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a date string, and have tested out my pattern on regex101. I think I am following the regex rules, but I'm obviously missing something, and the pattern is not matching the string.

My regex pattern is: `\s?(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thurs|Fri)day\s\d{0,2}(st|nd|rd|th)\s (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\,\s\d{4}`

The string I'm trying to match is:

> Monday 16th October, 2017

Which can appear in the document with or without lead/trailing whitespace(s).

Why is the pattern not matching?

Comment: `October` is not accounted for.

Comment: I just recognised both stupid errors on my part. I'll delete the question and try again.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Or just edit it.

Comment: `\d{0:2}` --> `\d{0,2}`

Comment: Also looks like you have additional space that you don't really need between `\s` and the months.

Comment: @wwii Gah!  corrected. Thanks

Comment: ok guys, got it with your help. I'll be deleting the question, unless someone wants to post an answer in the next few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By copying your regex from your post, I saw there's a redundant space here:

```
(st|nd|rd|th)\s (January|
               ↑
```

I'm not sure if it's a formation problem or not. Anyway, remove it and you should be fine.

Suggestion:

Depending on the language you're using (was tagged Python), use a library that parses the string for you, instead of having this (ugly) regex.